# SQL Server Report Builder: how to obtain SUM(Value) of each group

Tags: sql-server, group-by, reportbuilder

I have a report group by Field1 separated by pages, in each page I group by Field2.

So, my page is:

```
      Field1     Field2      SUM(Volume)

      ...

                 Total       SUM(Volume) --This is the value that I want to use!!
```

I have a Volume field that I want to do a percentage:

`Sum(Fields!Volume.Value)` is the aggregation of the value, that is correct
`sum(Fields!Volume.Value, "DataSet2")` is total of everything, that is incorrect because I want total of each page.

I am doing:

```
=(Sum(Fields!Volume.Value) * 100) / sum(Fields!Volume.Value, "DataSet1")
```

I am using, Report Builder 2.0 and I am not able to change.

I hope I explained myself ok,

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do aggregations with the total of a group (in this case, the Field2 group), using it as if it were a dataset. So, try this:

`(Sum(Fields!Volume.Value) * 100) / sum(Fields!Volume.Value, "Field2")`

But replace `Field2` with the actual name of that group.

Comment: The result in very field is 100, so I think it does not take the syntaxis.

Comment: No, I wasn't sure! Instead of Field2, I have to use Field1 because the value that I want is the total of the page. Thank you!!!